# Kong OIDC: discovery url timeout

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, minikube, kong

I am building the kong + kong-oidc + keycloak stack for my application. All of them are deployed into minikube cluster.

What I want to achieve is to perform Open ID Connect using Google Identity Provider.

I was referring to this blog post to set the things up https://www.jerney.io/secure-apis-kong-keycloak-1/.

The only difference is that instead of docker-compose, I used minikube to build the stacks up and the keycloak version is `image: jboss/keycloak:10.0.1`.

**Below are the steps I have taken:**

1. Setup Keycloak exposed as NodePort
2. Create keycloak realm + client
3. Setup Kong
4. Install kong-oidc
5. Define ingress gateway
6. Configure Kong ingress using OIDC configuration + keycloak client's details from step 2

When I setup it up using Ip address, everything works well. I managed browser my application, and it was redirected to Google Sign in page.

Next, when I put a bind my Ip address with a domain name + SSL encryption. The kong-oidc unable to reach my keycloak discovery URL.

below are the error I got from my browser. Due to the privacy, I have change all domain to `example.com`

`I browsed https://example.com/data`
It waited for around 1 min, then the results shows this:
`accessing discovery url (https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/.well-known/openid-configuration) failed: timeout`

I have a domain says `example.com`, and a subdomain `keycloak.example.com`.
Once I have setup Keycloak behind the Kong proxy, I have removed the NodePort settings.

Below are my ingress definitions:
**Ingress for `example.com`**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-api
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    konghq.com/plugins: oidc
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: gateway-api
    hosts:
    - example.com
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /data
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: data-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

**Ingress for `keycloak.example.com`**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gateway-keycloak
  annotations:
    konghq.com/plugins: transform-function
spec:
  rules:
  - host: keycloak.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: admin-keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
```

The `transform-function` was used to override the default port forward to ensure the Keycloak admin console able to access through `keycloak.example.com` using `https`

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: transform-function
disabled: false
config:
  functions:
    - ngx.var.upstream_x_forwarded_port=443
plugin: post-function
```

My OIDC plugin definition:

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: oidc
disabled: false
config:
  client_id: <client_id>
  client_secret: <client_secret>
  ssl_verify: "true"
  discovery: https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/.well-known/openid-configuration
  introspection_endpoint: http://admin-keycloak:8080/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
plugin: oidc
```

Also, I have set the keycloak environment with `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"`

The certificate also installed correctly, I can browser keycloak admin console using https.

Below are the logs from kong pod.
**Logs from `proxy` container**

```
2020/05/11 16:12:16 [error] 22#0: *87800 [lua] openidc.lua:483: openidc_discover(): accessing discovery url (https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/.well-known/openid-configuration) failed: timeout, client: 172.17.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /data HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com"
172.17.0.1 - - [11/May/2020:16:12:16 +0000] "GET /data HTTP/2.0" 500 130 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
```

No error messages from `ingress-controller` container.

I have run out of ideas on how to troubleshoot this error. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Hi, can You add Your minikube version? Also does the error from `proxy` container appear at the same time as the timeout from Your request?

Comment: Hi @Piotr Malec, below are my minikube version, 
Minikube: `v1.9.2 (driver = none)`, 
Docker: `19.03.8`, 
Kubernetes: `v1.18.0`. 
Kubectl:
`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2", GitCommit:"52c56ce7a8272c798dbc29846288d7cd9fbae032", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-04-16T11:56:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`. And yes, the `proxy` container error was coming from my timeout request

Comment: On top of this, if I browse this link `https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/.well-known/openid-configuration` directly from browser, the link is working.

Comment: Apparently, I found out some hint on where is the problem coming from. Issue here is that the discovery URL `https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/example/.well-known/openid-configuration` need to be accessible from both Kong's `proxy` and internet. At the moment, `keycloak.example.com` only acessible from internet but not from pods inside cluster because the pods has no DNS record for `keycloak.example.com`. I know I can use the host IP address, but if I still want to use the DNS domain name, how can I configure this in Kubernetes?

Comment: This is what I have tried, I remote into the Kong proxy perform the `curl` command on the domain or IP itself `curl example.com` or `curl keycloak.example.com` it cannot connect to the server. By doing so, it actually redirect back to the Kong proxy (the ingress) itself, I suspect is because Kong does not support redirect to itself, am I correct?